# WinUI 3 Binding to a static property

Tags: winui-3

In WPF you could use the following code to bind a control to a static property:

Xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=(local:ViewModel.Txt), Mode=TwoWay, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</TextBox>
```

Static view model:

```
public static class ViewModel
{
    private static string txt;
    public static event EventHandler TxtChanged;

    public static string Txt
    {
        get
        {
            return txt;
        }

        set
        {
            if (txt != value)
            {
                txt = value;
                TxtChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in a winUI 3 project. VS 2022 doesn't give any errors in the user code, but shows an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' error in Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.Compiler.interop.targets.

Is binding to static properties supported in winUI 3, either using Binding or x:Bind? Thanks for any info.

Comment: Following this case https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6048 it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

`x:Bind` works:

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind local:ViewModel.Txt, Mode=TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't giving two-way binding on my machine. Changes made in the UI text box are reflected in the Txt property in the static view model, but if I change the Txt property in code, the updated value of Txt isn't reflected in the UI (whereas it is in WPF).

Comment: And if I use a one-way mode as below, this also doesn't update the UI when Txt is changed in code (it does in WPF):

`<Button Click="Btn_Click" Content="{x:Bind local:ViewModel.Txt, Mode=OneWay}" />`

The above also gives the following warning:

"WMC1506 OneWay bindings require at least one of their steps to support raising notifications when their value changes"

suggesting the control isn't recognizing the TxtChanged event.

Any thoughts? I'm new to this so may be missing something obvious.

Comment: You haven't implemented any change notification, have you? Please ask a new question if you have another issue.